# Give System Managed Identity access to classic SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-managed-identity

I've got an Azure App Service that needs access to a classic SQL Server (non-Azure SQL, not SQL Managed Instance) and I'd prefer to do this via System Managed Identity. This is enabled on the App Service and a corresponding Enterprise Application is created on Azure AD.

The SQL Server is also connected to this Azure AD and User accounts on the AD already have access to the database. However I can't find how to create a login for the Enterprise Application. If this was an Azure SQL database I could do it with `CREATE LOGIN [AZUREAD\app] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` but this does not work on a classic SQL Server, only on Azure SQL/MI.

A solution would be to use SQL accounts and reference the login/password in the connection strings, but as mentioned I'd much rather use Azure AD for authentication.

Comment: `CREATE LOGIN [AZUREAD\app] FROM WINDOWS` maybe? That's assuming the SQL Server's operating system is set up with Azure AD federation, so that it trusts that domain. This question is probably best migrated to [dba.se]

Comment: That doesn't work as the Managed Identity is an Enterprise Application and not a regular AD user account. It gives: `Windows NT user or group 'AZUREAD\app' not found. Check the name again.`

Comment: What do you mean by classic SQL server, SQL server on a VM ?

Comment: @Thomas exactly. We can't use Azure SQL due to reasons out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: SQL Server 2022 includes Azure AD authentication [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/azure-ad-authentication-sql-server-overview?view=sql-server-ver16)
Using integrated security or an access token it will be possible to authenticate with an App Registration.

This is currently in preview with no RTM date specified.